# Norm defined by matrix

Tags: normed-spaces

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ real matrix and for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define $\|\mathbf{x}\|_A = \sqrt{\mathbf{x}^T A \mathbf{x}}$.

Under what conditions on the matrix $A$ is $\|\cdot \|_A$ a norm on $\mathbf{R}^n$?

Comment: symmetric positive definite

Comment: Thanks. Is there a proof of this somewhere that you can link to or reproduce?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011563/a-question-about-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-and-norm.