# Prove that $f(u+v)\le f(u) +f(v)$ being $f(u)= Au\cdot u\in\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric and positive definite matrix. Consider the function
$$f: u\in\mathbb R^n\mapsto f(u)= (Au\cdot u)^{1/2}\in\mathbb R.$$

Let $\|\cdot\|_1$ denote a norm and set
$$n(u):= \big(\|u\|^2_1 + (f(u))^2\big)^{1/2}.$$

As an exercise, I have to prove that
$$n(u+v)\le n(u) +n(v)\quad\forall u,v\in\mathbb R^n.$$

I am stuck at this point. Using the triangle inequality for $\|\cdot\|_1$ I write
$$n(u+v) = \big(\|u+v\|^2_1 + (f(u+v))^2\big)^{1/2}\le \big(\|u\|^2_1 + \|v\|^2_1 +2\|u\|_1 \|v\|_1 + A(u+v)\cdot(u+v)\big)^{1/2} = \big(\|u\|^2_1 + \|v\|^2_1 +2\|u\|_1 \|v\|_1 + f(u) + f(v) +2Au\cdot v\big)^{1/2} $$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is $A$ positive semi-definite?

Comment: @blomp, yes. I have edited the question.

Comment: What is happening here, is that your function $f$ is going to be a [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). The poperty you're asking for is the triangle inequality for the norm. I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1011563/1198970) question should sort you out.

Comment: The question is: is the function a norm? I can not see why the triangle inequality holds true.

Comment: Clearly, $f(2u)=2f(u)$ fails. So it is not a norm.

Comment: I made a transcription error in the exercise (I have just asked a classmate). I edit the question.

Comment: The correct version with an accepted answer is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011563/norm-with-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The title is still wrong.

Comment: Please do not delete your question immediately after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b$ are norms then $n=(a^2+b^2)^{1/2}$ is as well. For this question we will only bother to check triangle inequality. Since $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ is the standard norm on $\mathbb R^2$, it satisfies the triangle inequality: for all $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2 \in \mathbb R$, we have $((x_1+x_2)^2+(y_1+y_2)^2)^{1/2}\le (x_1^2+y_1^2)^{1/2} + (x_2^2+y_2^2)^{1/2}$ so it follows
\begin{align} &n(u+v)\\&=(a(u+v)^2+b(u+v)^2)^{1/2} \\&\le ((a(u)+a(v))^2+(b(u)+b(v))^2)^{1/2} \\ &\le (a(u)^2+b(u)^2)^{1/2} + (a(v)^2+b(v)^2)^{1/2} \\&= n(u) + n(v),\end{align}
as required.

1. This applies to your $f(u) = (u^TAu)^{1/2}$ (putting $a=\|\cdot\|_1$ and $b=f$) since e.g. it satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz, see [Norm with symmetric positive definite matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011563/norm-with-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1) for detail (link from above comment).
2. for the title question with $f(u)=u^TAu$ without the ${(\phantom{u^TAu})}^{1/2}$, if $A$ is given by $Ae_1 = \binom{100}{1}$ and $Ae_2 = \binom{1}{100}$ then note $e_1 A e_2 = e_2 A e_1 = 1 > 0$ and consequently $f(e_1+e_2)>f(e_1)+f(e_2)$.

Comment: Calvin Khor, it seems from the comment that the problem if $f$ not being a norm.

Comment: @C.Bishop: With your latest changes $f(u)= (Au\cdot u)^{1/2}$ the function $f$ *is* a norm.

Comment: @MartinR, I still have troubles in proving the triangle inequality.